# Jquery array returns undefined after running through initial array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, background

I am trying to fix this background fader,
It works but it returns some of the values as undefined and I cannot figure it out,
any help would be greatly appreciated.

The php just reads a directory and gets the image filepaths then creates hidden spans with that text in it.

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
         /* DocReady */
         var counter = 0;
         var faderImgs = new Array();
         $('span.entry').each(function () {
           var value = 'images/bg/' + $(this).text();
           faderImgs.push(value);
           $('<img />').attr('src', value).appendTo(this).css('display', 'none');
         })

         /* DocReady */

         var intId = setInterval(faderBg, 8000);
         var numItems = $('span.entry').length;

         function faderBg() {

           $('.background-fader').animate({
             'opacity': '0'
           }, 2000, function () {
             $('.background-fader').css('background-image', 'url(' + faderImgs[counter] + ')')
             $('.background-fader').animate({
               'opacity': '1'
             }, 2000)

           })
           counter++;
           if (counter > numItems) {
             var counter = 0;
           }
         }

       });
```

----------------------------EDIT ---------------------------------------

Awesome thanks for the help guys, 
all working again now.

Answer (score 2):

Your counter is spilling off the end of the array. You want to set it back to zero when it's **equal** to "numItems", not when it's greater; JavaScript arrays start at zero, so the biggest index is `numItems - 1`.

```
       counter++;
       if (counter >= numItems) { // >=, not >
         counter = 0;
       }
```

Also, you don't need `var` when you're setting "counter" back to zero.  You should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to set the "src" attribute of those `<img>` elements you create. (I'm not sure why you even bother to create those, unless perhaps it's to pre-fetch the images into the browser cache. If so, there's no need to append an `<img>` element to the DOM — just create an `Image` instance and set its "src" property.)

*edit* — @charlietfl correctly points out that that stray `var` would cause serious problems for you, because it would result in there being a *local* "counter" variable in that inner function. In fact if it were there in your real code I can't imagine how it could work at all, as "counter" would always be `undefined` (or `NaN` I guess after the postincrement).

Comment: big emphasis on don't need `var`! Due to scope within function it creates a completely different variable